# Pointer to next/prev pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm using a convolution process using a 3x3 grid over a 2d image that is represented in a 1d array. I am iterating over certain pixels and need access to the surrounding pixels (ignoring edge cases). Is it possible to have a pointer that always points to a location next to another pointer?

```
int* a = new int[5];
//populate with data (0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
int* b = &a[2]; //4
int* c = b+1;   //6
b++;            //b->6, c->6
                //What if after b++ I want c->8?
```

Is there any way to make a pointer relative to another pointer such that when the main pointer is changed, the other pointers change with it? So, a pointer that always points to the neighbor of another pointer.

Comment: No need to create a new pointer. `b[1]` will always point to the next item of `b`, whatever its current value. Similar with `b[-1]`.

Comment: Thanks, this is along the lines of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing `b` does not change `c`. If you want both pointers to move in parallel, you must increment both of them:

```
b++;
c++;
```

This seems like more trouble than it's worth, though, since you can just do `b + 1` to find the "next" element in the array.